# JQuery colorbox doesn't work with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, colorbox

I have really basic colorbox script:

```
<script src="data/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/data/scripts/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".InternalIMG").colorbox({rel:'InternalIMG', transition:"fade"})
});
</script>
```

Everything works in static document.

Example of code:

```
<a class="InternalIMG" href="/data/images/gallery/testing/UK.png" title="Absolutní schéma">
    <div class="image_left" style="background-image: url('data/images/gallery/testing/UK.png');"></div>
</a>
```

But when I use it in PHP variable, it simply doesn't work:

```
      $gal_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gomi_galerie_fotky WHERE section=" . $_GET['id'], $link);
      if (mysql_num_rows($gal_query) != 0) {
          while($gal_result=mysql_fetch_assoc($gal_query)) {
              if ($gallery_count % 3 == 0) {$gallery_rows .= '</tr><tr valign="middle" align="center">';};

              $gallery_rows .= '<td width="150px" height="150px" align="center" valign="middle" style="overflow: hidden;"><a class="InternalIMG" href="/data/images/gallery/testing/UK.png" title="Absolutní schéma"><div class="image_left" style="background-image: url(/data/images/gallery/thumbs/' . $gal_result['id'] . '.' . $gal_result['type'] . ');" title="' . $gal_result['body'] . '"></div></a></td>';
              $gallery_count++;  
          }

          $gallery = '<table align="center" border="0" width="150px" height="150px" style="table-layout:fixed"><tr valign="middle" align="center">' . $gallery_rows . '</tr></table>';
```

Maybe is problem with php file (these php variables are in another [included] php file).

Thank for your help.

Comment: Also, you can't have a `div` inside an `a` tag.

Comment: putvande: On static page it works. Why do you think it could be the problem?

Skippy: Those are global variable. I have one PHP file (index.php) where is all the design except CSS (It's basicly HTML file with some echo-s, where is dynamic content) and than special PHP files for the dynamic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the brace of `if`. Add a `}` to end of php code.

Comment: It's closed, it's only mistake of copy-paste.